# Troubles with kernel 4.2.0-17 and LAN/VGA Combo Port

Tags: kernel

What happened? Since the latest kernel upgrade from 4.2.0-16 to 4.2.0-17 my Aspire V5 Notebook with Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 does not recognize the external monitor nor my lan port anymore. When I boot with 4.2.0-16 there's no problem...

Both lan and vga are connected via the Acer LAN/VGA Combo Port which seems to be a proprietary version of a Mini DisplayPort. But to be fair, also wifi and bluetooth seem to be unavailable while those have nothing to do with that port.

Anyone have similar issues with 4.2.0-17? Or did something weird happen when the kernel was installed? If so, what can I do about that?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having similar problems with Ubuntu 15.10 and kernel 4.2.0-17 on my Samsung Ativ 9. None of my USB ports work, Wifi is down, and compiz is using 150% CPU. There is some sort of regression in the 4.2.0-17 kernel, because it's no longer detecting my Haswell CPU; instead, it's rolling back to the llvmpipe software graphics driver (which explains why compiz is going crazy).

For now, you can reboot your machine and choose Advanced Options in the grub boot menu to go back to the 4.2.0-16 kernel. My guess is that this problem will be noticed, patched, and a new kernel update will roll out soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling there where some packages (kernel headers and extra's) missing from the first upgrade. Maybe it was just too soon that I executed the upgrade while these missing packages where not released yet? In any case, gonna answer my own question here to share the steps it took to resolve this:

1. reboot and select the advanced boot options at the Grub boot prompt, then choose the previous 16 kernel and boot with that.
2. log in and open Software Center, search for "kernel 17" (without the quotes)

Now check if "linux-headers-4.2.0-17" and "linux-image-extras-4.2.0-17" are not installed. If they are in the list but not installed, you may try to install them direcctly (don't know if that will fix it) but because I was not sure I proceeded with removing the 17 kernel first:

3. select "linux-image-4.2.0-17-generic" in the short list (you may need to click the "Show technical items" link at the bottom) and hit the Remove button
4. confirm the question to remove "linux-signed-image-4.2.0-17-generic" and "linux-image-generic" too
5. open the Update Manager and let it run.

Update Manager should tell you there are new kernel upgrades. If it doesn't, then go back to the Software Center and search for "linux-image-generic" and install that.

Let it upgrade/install all packages (more than the first time!) and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with my mini-DisplayPort adapter after switching to Ubuntu 15.10. Problems: the external monitor doesn't get recognized at all, or it gets recognized but only as 1024x768 (and it's a 1980x1024 monitor).

It's because of the 4.2.0-18 kernel; if I boot with the old kernel (3.19.0-33-generic) everything works again.

Let's hope they fix this in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. I found that updating to a 4.3.xx version kernel seems to have fixed things.